# Spring Hibernate access joined database field

Tags: hibernate, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

my database tables:

```
cities(id serial, name varchar(40);
weather(id serial, city_id int, temp int, date date)
```

cities.id = weather.city_id

In Spring I have same POJO as the fields in database.

for example City.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CITIES")
public class City {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CITIES_ID_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CITIES_ID_SEQ", sequenceName="cities_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;
        //here come getters and setters
```

DAO - so this will be returned to controller, which sends it to JSP:

```
public Weather getWeatherById(Integer id) {
    return (Weather) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Weather.class, id);
}
```

Controller:

```
model.addAttribute("weather", weatherService.getWeatherById(id));
```

Question is that, how can I access the `cities.name` from JSP? Or that is not possible, without special query?

Comment: Is the city part of the Weather abstraction? If yes, you can access it and it's name from there.

Comment: @mkro : what do you mean under abstraction?

Comment: as the answer by @danny.lesnik suggests: You need a class for the Weather information and that class should be connected to Cities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two objects should have biderectional one-to-one releationship.

```
public class City{

@One-To-One
private Weather weather;

}
```

and the second class:

```
public class Weather {

@One-to-One
private City city;

}
```

then you can fetch city and get its weather using getWeather() or you can fetch weather and get its city.

Alternatively, you can use HQL join statement to fetch city:

```
from City c join c.weather wheather where wheather.id = :id .
```

Comment: Must I change anything in my database? Or the `city_id` may remain to int? Or must I create somekind of relation in database? At the moment I just have these two tables, only I know that `cities.id = weather.city_id`

Comment: Acctually Hibernate can make all required work for you, you just need to create correct releationship: I just recommend you to read the article about one-to-one relationship it may clear picture for you:http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, this does not seem like a one-to-one relationship to me but rather a many-to-one. Try using the following for the children:

```
public class Weather {

@Many-to-One
private City city;

}
```

and for the parent:

```
public class City{

@One-To-Many
private Weather weather;

}
```